# Ruby Shopping Cart

Tags: ruby

I'm new at Ruby and I'm having difficulty finishing this shopping cart program. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone tell me how to get the last two lines to output the code that I have in comments next to them? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
class Store

    def initialize
       @products = {"eggs" => 1.5, "bread" => 3.00, "granola cereal" => 3.4, "coffee" => 2.3, "pie" => 4.7}
       @cart = []
    end

    def add_to_cart( item )
        @cart << item
    end

    def add_product( item, price )
        @products[item] = price
    end

    def cart_total
        @cart.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + @products[item]}
    end

    def items
        @products.join(', ')
    end
end


store = Store.new                  
store.add_to_cart "eggs"
store.add_to_cart "Pie"
store.add_to_cart "bread"
puts store.cart                     # output: eggs, pie, bread
printf "$%6.2f", store.cart_total   # output: $ 9.20
```

When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
nil can't be coerced into Float
(repl):17:in `+'
(repl):17:in `block in total'
(repl):17:in `each'
(repl):17:in `inject'
(repl):17:in `total'
(repl):28:in `<main>main>'
```

Comment: Check the capitalisation of `pie` ;-)

Comment: Do remember that floating point values are always approximations so using them for monetary calculations is trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is a capitalized letter in `store.add_to_cart "Pie"`. This adds the string `"Pie"` to your `@cart` array. When you iterate over `@cart` using `#inject`, `@products["Pie"]` returns `nil`, because there is no key for `"Pie"` in your hash (the keys are case-sensitive). You can't add `nil` to `sum`, which is a float.

Try again with a lowercase "pie" and it should work fine. Or to avoid capitalization issues in the future, change your `cart_total` method to `@cart.inject(0){ |sum, item| sum + @products[item.downcase] }`.